# How do I reduce chart size so that long axis text can be totally seen?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

See how the x axis text falls out of the image?  I could reduce the size of the labels, but I'd rather reduce the size of the chart.  How do I do that?

I've tried adjusting `x` and `y` for `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(x,y))`, and also tried `plt.figure(figsize(x,y))`

but all they seem to do is change the window size that pops up when I run the script.  When I maximize out the window I get the same problem.

I've played with `plt.margins(x)` but that changes the margins inside of the chart when I want to change the chart itself.

Comment: You can just right align them with `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha="right")`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I needed to add

`plt.tight_layout()`

and then adjust `x` and `y` in

`fig=plt.figuresize(x,y)`